# '$ not defined' | Server side rendering in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have using Angular 6.0.3 and I am using `@ng-toolkit/universal` to archive server-side rendering. I am able to generate build successfully using this command '`npm run build:prod`' but I found the following issue while running this command `'npm run server': $ is not defined`

> root@asif:/home/asif/projects/dp/df# npm run server
>
> dp@0.0.0 server /home/asif/projects/dp/df
>
> node local.js
>
> Listening on: http://localhost:4200
>   ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at HomeComponent.module.exports../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:124683:9)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:9341:19)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10605:20)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10567:16)
>       at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:11107:5)
>       at Object.updateDirectives (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:124631:473)
>       at Object.updateDirectives (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10896:72)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10549:14)
>       at callViewAction (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10790:21)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (/home/asif/projects/dp/df/dist/server.js:10753:17)

that is the component file '`home.component.ts`'

```
ngOnInit() {

$(document).ready(function () {
  var owl = $('#client');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    loop:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 10000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    pagination: true,
    navigation: true,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1

      },
      600: {
        items: 2
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  });
});
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Lucier use this `declare const $: any;`

Comment: @Abhishek i already declared

Comment: in 'home.component.ts'  or 'server.js' generate after build

Comment: okay let me try.

Comment: after using 'import * as $ from "jquery"; i found this error: ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(56,11): error TS2339: Property 'owlCarousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Comment: do you use webpack?

Comment: @MortezaFathnia no

Comment: cast your owl to <any> like:

var owl = (<any>$("#client"))

Comment: after cast owl then i found document is not defiend.

Comment: Look at the [docs here](https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis). Depending on what you need exactly, you might be able to provide it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, why are you using jQuery together with Angular? You should not do that. It's the whole point with frameworks like Angular and React, to not mess with the DOM manually. You are trying to run jQuery on the server side. However, jQuery requires a browser environment to work (since it talks with the DOM), and on server side, you don't have any DOM tree to manipulate. Therefore, things like `window` or `document` won't exist until the code runs in the browser.

Comment: Agree, jQuery should not be used here at all. All that he wrote should be done inside ngOnInit() or ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hooks.